# No puedo grabar un archivo de una URL con NSData y writeToFile

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tengo un código muy sencillo para grabar un archivo bajado de una URL en la SandBox. El archivo lo llego a guardar en un objeto `NSData` pero a la hora de escribirlo con `writeToFile` no lo hace. En cambio tengo otro código que es prácticamente igual que sí lo escribe pero con la salvedad que el directorio que creo es temporal con `NSTemporaryDirectory`.

```
NSString *documentsDir = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"midirectorio"];    
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
BOOL result = [data writeToFile:documentsDir atomically:YES];
if (result) { 
    NSLog(@"WF OK %@",url);
} else  {
    NSLog(@"WF KO %@",url);
}
```

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Es posible que el directorio `documentsDir` no exista? Si no existe, deberías crearlo antes de escribir el archivo.

Comment: Gracias, uno de los fallos también era que no había creado el directorio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el error radica en conceptos. `writeToFile` require el path y nombre del archivo donde deseas guardar la data, no funciona con solo el directorio. Prueba el siguiente código:

```
NSString *documentsDir = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"midirectorio"];

//asegurate que el directorio exista
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:documentsDir isDirectory:nil]) {
    [fm createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}

NSString *filePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"miarchivo"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL result = [data writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
if (result) {
    NSLog(@"WF OK %@", url);
} else  {
    NSLog(@"WF KO %@ %@",url, error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Si todavia presenta problema puedes comentar aquí el mensaje que imprime `error.localizedDescription`.

Comment: igual puedes utilizar `[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]` en lugar del `[data writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];`, el que coloque tiene la ventaja de obtener un mensaje de error si algo falla

Comment: Gracias, volvi a mirar el código y entre otras cosas ademas del path, necesitaba crear un directorio si este no existía con el objeto NSFileManager